# como saber si el primer y el ultimo elemento del array son iguales en php

Tags: php

deseo saber si el ultimo y el primer elemento del array son iguales

```
 $destinos_=explode('-',$destino_);

    if(end($destinos_)==reset($destinos_)){
      echo "son iguales";
```

no logo que entre al if

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo del contenido de `$destinos_`? Por qué no usas los índices del primer y último elemento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP tiene dos métodos dedicados a acceder al primero y al último elemento de un array:

- [**`reset()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.reset.php)

  > Establece el puntero interno de un array a su primer elemento
- [**`end()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.end.php)

  > Establece el puntero interno de un array a su último elemento

Los métodos son hermanos, y conviene que trabajen juntos, por rendimiento y por uniformidad del código.

En estos dos casos el código es el mismo, y los arrays son distintos:

### Caso 1

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,1);
$a=reset($array);
$z=end($array);
$msg=($a===$z) ? "$a y $z son iguales" : "$a y $z NO son iguales";
echo $msg;
```

**Salida:**

```
1 y 1 son iguales
```

### Caso 2

El código es el mismo, pero el array tiene otra estructura y ponemos un dato distinto en el último para probar.

```
$array=array("elemento1" => 1, "elemento2" => 2, "elemento3" => 3);
$a=reset($array);
$z=end($array);
$msg=($a===$z) ? "$a y $z son iguales" : "$a y $z NO son iguales";
echo $msg;
```

**Salida:**

```
1 y 3 NO son iguales
```

### En resumen

`end()` y `reset()` parecen ser los métodos más naturales para acceder al primer y último elemento de un array de forma uniforme.

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo que lo hagas mas simple de este modo:

- Usa el método `end` propio de PHP que moverá el puntero al último elemento del vector y devolverá `false` si este esta vacío
- Asigna a una variable el elemento de la primer posición, indicando entre corchetes por el índice 0
- Usa triple `===` para comparar valor y tipo de dato
- De esta forma no necesitarías de forma explícita el uso de un bucle y un condicional

**Ejemplo**

```
<?php

$datos = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,1);
$elementoInicio = $datos[0];
$elementoFinal  = end($datos);

echo $elementoInicio === $elementoFinal;
```

**Resultado**

> 1

Si.... también funciona para vectores de tipo asociativo, es decir de tipo **`clave => valor`**, donde:

- En lugar de indicar el índice numérico del primer elemento; lo harás por su clave

**Ejemplo**

```
$datos = array("elemento1" => 1, "elemento2" => 2, "elemento3" => 1);
$elementoInicio = $datos["elemento1"];
$elementoFinal  = end($datos);

echo $elementoInicio === $elementoFinal;
```

Resultado:

> 1

**Referencias**

- [Método `end`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.end.php)